# Creating n Object of array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am having issues understanding how to create an array of `n` objects in Java.

This is the constructor of class `ServicePath` as follows:

```
public ServicePath(String id) {
   this.id = id;
}
```

This is the elements of the array that I would like to create the objects.

```
String ServicePathArrays[] = {"SH11","SH13","SH17","SH110","SH111","SH112","SH115", ...}
```

I tried the following, but it creates it manually.

```
ServicePath[] servicePathArray = new ServicePath[ServicePathArrays.length];
```

For example, manually it creates the following

```
ServicePath[0] = new ServicePath("SH11");
ServicePath[1] = new ServicePath("SH13");
..
..
```

I would like to create it automatically using 
`String ServicePathArrays` in such way:

```
ServicePath[0].id = "SH11";
ServicePath[1].id = "SH12";
ServicePath[2].id = "SH13";
..
..
```

Comment: Are you looking for the *most compact* way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done using the functional behavior of jdk8+ :

```
String servicePathArray[] = {"SH11", "SH13", "SH17",
                             "SH110", "SH111", "SH112", "SH115"};
List<ServicePath> collection = Stream.of(servicePathArray)
                                     .map(ServicePath::new)
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(collection);
```

Comment: It's more succinct to have `Stream.of(servicePathArray)` than `Arrays.asList(servicePathArray).stream()`. And even more succinct is `Stream.of("SH11", "SH13", ..., "SH115")`.

Comment: I agree :+1 for this hint

Answer (score 1):

```
String ServicePathArrays[] = {"SH11","SH13","SH17","SH110","SH111","SH112","SH115", ...};
ServicePath[] servicePathArray = new ServicePath[ServicePathArrays.length];
for(int i = 0; i < ServicePathArrays.length; i++) {
    servicePathArray [i] = new ServicePath(ServicePathArrays[i]);
}
```